# AWS EC-2 Ubuntu 18.04 browser based SSH is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just created an AWS EC-2 instance with Ubuntu 18.04
I do want to use browser based SSH to connect to my instance.

[image]

Then I got this error when I try to connect

[image]

This is a very generic error and I am unable to find what's wrong here?

Is this a probelm with my user name "ubuntu"
or something to do with inbound rules?

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu this is **not enabled** by default (but, it works out-of-the-box on Amazon Linux 2). Usually to enable this, **installing** `ec2-instance-connect` should be enough:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install ec2-instance-connect
```

If you launch such instances often, you can install this through `UserData`.